# How to Create a UpdateForm with TemplateView?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-leaflet

I need to create a UpdateForm with a TemplateView. Why with TemplateView? Because, I has a attribute what is geo_location, and I'm using LeafLet maps, and LeafLet maps doesn't work with generic.UpdateView or others the same type.

Here my views from Update:

```
class UpdateStore(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'store_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('register:store_list')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        store_id = kwargs['store']
        store = get_object_or_404(Store, pk=store_id)
        form = StoreForm(request.POST, on_edit=True)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('register:store_list'))
        else:
            context = self.get_context_data()
            context['data_form'] = form
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)

        return self.get(request)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        store_id = self.kwargs['store']
        store = get_object_or_404(Store, pk=store_id)

        data = {
            'name': store.name,
            'description': store.description,
            'address': store.address,
            'geo_loc': store.geo_loc,
            'opened': store.opened
        }

        context['editing'] = True
        context['data_form'] = StoreForm(initial=data, on_edit=True)
        context['store'] = store
        return context
```

Here is my template code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}

{% block extra_css %}
    {% leaflet_css plugins="forms" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1> Update Store </h1>

    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form }}

        {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit">
        {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Save
        </button>
        {% endbuttons %}

    </form>

{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
    {% leaflet_js plugins="forms" %}
{% endblock %}
```

I trying this, but in my template, the Forms doesn't load, and my template are blanked :(. Someone knows why? I need another method for get anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally I find it strange that you do not use the `FormMixin` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#formmixin, it handles most of the workflow of the `Form` itself.

Comment: *LeafLet maps doesn't work with generic.UpdateView or others the same type* What makes you say this? I don't see how a leaflet map is affected by the Django view.

Comment: I’ve never heard about FormMixin . Will try this, but I tryed other methods like CreateView and ListView, and leaflet doesn’t work. Only works with TemplateView

Comment: *leaflet doesn't work* isn't enough information. For us to be able to help you, please show a simple, reproducible example.

Comment: In the CreateView, leaflet doesn’t work, the map doesn’t show in template. And, in the ListView, the map show up, but doesn’t show a pin with location for that object.

Comment: And, when I try write in TemplateView the form for create a object, the map works normally.

Comment: It is also important to show the code on the template where you are using the form, so people can help you find the problem.

Comment: its ok, done @dethos

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you place the form in the `data_form` key of the `context`:

```
context['data_form'] = StoreForm(initial=data, on_edit=True)
```

and then on the template you try to use it with `{{form}}` instead of `{{data_form}}`. After that the form should be rendered.

Comment: ok, I got it, but I tryed, and now I have this. `__call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'` :/

Comment: That is a problem with your code that is not related to your question. Are you sure that none of your `store` fields, that you use on `data`, is a relation? it might be missing an `.all()` for example.

Comment: that's the problem, you are passing the manager to the form, when you should pass the queryset

Comment: How I fix it? Can you help me?